# Lenovo z50-70 Nvidia 331 Graphics Freeze

Tags: nvidia

Problem : Random graphics freeze when using Nvidia drivers.

Installation : Ubuntu 14.04.2 64bit

Workaround : Use Intel integrated graphics instead of Nvidia.

Bug has been already reported [in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/+bug/1362848)

I am now running on Intel integrated graphics and the system runs fine. However, when I switch to dedicated graphics (NVIDIA GeForce 820M), after a while system freezes.

*Any help will be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/

Comment: The problem is my system freezes randomly, when using nvidia drivers. No problem at all when I don't use it. But I need to use the graphics card, so please suggest a solution

Comment: Much better.  I've voted to re-open...  Once 4 more people have voted to re-open, please drop me a note @Fabby and I'll come back and answer your question.

Comment: @SachinThampan as you've noted there is a bug reported for the Nvidia 331 series drivers.

Comment: @Fabby: The question is opened again ;)